# GTK Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gtk, 17.10

I use Ubuntu 17.10.

When I start *gedit*, *virt-manager* as root I get a dubious error message:
`gtk warning cannot open display :0.0`

I read many posts but none works with Ubuntu 17.10.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Other root applications are broken on Wayland too (see [bug 1713313](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713313) and [bug 1713311](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713311)
).

Comment: I use the new AMD Cpu with Gigabyte so i need Kernel 4.10 >. Thans i read this post and it is now clear.

Answer (score 15):

By default 17.10 does not allow root to access your display.

Try the command `xhost +si:localuser:root` 
then launch gedit with root privilege.

Comment: I got the same error message when i set the xhost local:root.

Comment: try `xhost +si:localuser:root` seems thy changed the command also

Answer (score -1):

There is an alternative method by typing these commands:

> su -
>
> gedit

When you will type 1st command, It will prompt for the password.

Note that by this way **gedit** will open as the root user.